# ENGINE-09005 Could not parse BPMN process. Errors:

Tags: camunda, camunda-modeler

I just started learning camunda and trying to deploy diagram, I get this error please tell me how to fix it?

```
ENGINE-09005 Could not parse BPMN process. Errors:
```

* src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'extension' to a(n) 'element declaration' component. | resource diagram_1.bpmn | line 15 | column 70
* src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'rootElement' to a(n) 'element declaration' component. | resource diagram_1.bpmn | line 16 | column 72
* src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'bpmndi:BPMNDiagram' to a(n) 'element declaration' component. | resource diagram_1.bpmn | line 17 | column 79
* src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'relationship' to a(n) 'element declaration' component. | resource diagram_1.bpmn | line 18 | column 73
* cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'bpmn:process'. One of '{"http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/MODEL":import}' is expected. | resource diagram_1.bpmn | line 3 | column 58 [ deploy-error ]

Comment: Can you paste the first few lines of the bpmn file? The first error seems to appear in line 3 and some more on lines 15-18.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<bpmn:definitions xmlns:bpmn="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/MODEL" xmlns:bpmndi="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/DI" xmlns:dc="http://www.omg.org/spec/DD/20100524/DC" xmlns:di="http://www.omg.org/spec/DD/20100524/DI" xmlns:camunda="http://camunda.org/schema/1.0/bpmn" id="Definitions_01da8st" targetNamespace="http://bpmn.io/schema/bpmn" exporter="Camunda Modeler" exporterVersion="3.7.1">
  <bpmn:process id="Process_0qky0f0" name="Test" isExecutable="true" camunda:versionTag="1">